# Python - Append input to .txt but deletes prior data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I´m trying to append input to a .txt and succeed to do so, however the data previously present in my .txt file gets overwritten by the data inputted. I wish for the data to stay with the input added.

Heres my code so far:

```
def tilføjMedlem():
    while True: 
        tilføjFornavn = input("Skriv fornavn på det medlem du ønsker at tilføje: (Tast q for at afslutte)")
        if tilføjFornavn == 'q':
            break
        else:
            tilføjEfternavn= input("Efternavn:")
            tilføjJollypoints= input("Jollypoints:")
            tilføjInstagram = input("Instagram:")
            tilføjMedlemSiden = input('Medlem siden:')

    with open('fans.txt', 'a') as text_file:
        text_file.write(tilføjFornavn+" "+tilføjEfternavn+" "+tilføjJollypoints+" "+tilføjInstagram+" "+tilføjMedlemSiden)

tilføjMedlem()
```

Comment: You are not overwriting the content in the file, the variables you're using are overwritten on every iteration of the while loop. So only the last set of vallues will be written to the file.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. Do you mean the `open` statement to be in or outside the `while` loop? Fix the question.

Comment: When I read the code, I expect that only last 4 inputs is append to the .txt file. And it does. So no issues with your code. Tested with python 3.6.

Comment: Should be closed and moved to SE code review since the code works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the indentation of the `with open()` function.

Your code is re-assigning the values to variables you have declared. It will call write to file function only once with the last values entered in the variables after user had entered `q` to quit.

```py
def tilføjMedlem():
    while True: 
        tilføjFornavn = input("Skriv fornavn på det medlem du ønsker at tilføje: (Tast q for at afslutte)")
        if tilføjFornavn == 'q':
            break
        else:
            tilføjEfternavn= input("Efternavn:")
            tilføjJollypoints= input("Jollypoints:")
            tilføjInstagram = input("Instagram:")
            tilføjMedlemSiden = input('Medlem siden:')

        with open('fans.txt', 'a') as text_file:
            text_file.write(tilføjFornavn+" "+tilføjEfternavn+" "+tilføjJollypoints+" "+tilføjInstagram+" "+tilføjMedlemSiden)

tilføjMedlem()
```

Comment: This is not the solution. The code works without changing the `with` indentation.

Comment: The code won't work as expected by the user in question, if the indentation of `while` and `with` is same. Reason: `while` loop will execute until user enter `q` and once it exits then `open()` will be called only once.

Comment: The orginal code works but the functionality is not as the user expects, using the while loops indicates the need for a quick way to add multiple records untill the user decides to quit te program.

Comment: @DorianTurba: The code requires an indentation fix in order to work according to the user's requirement. I'm not sure what you are suggesting.

Comment: There is nothing to do, since the issue is: `the data previously present in my .txt file gets overwritten`. Thats wrong. If the issue is that data previously given in the console by input, then Trine Klitgaard Sørensen need to change the question since it mislead the reader.

Comment: The code work. It append to the file the last inputs before pressing `q`. If it is not the intended behavior, then the question needs to be edit.

Comment: @DorianTurba: Try using the code provided in the question and enter inputs multiple times. Try to add more than two lines to the file and you will see what I'm trying to tell.

Answer (score 1):

## The code work

Actually, the code append the text correctly to the .txt file. But it overwrite the previous input you may enter in the `while` loop.
If the input getter behave like intended, then there is no issues with your code. It get the 4 last inputs you enter, then `append` them in the file without overwriting it:

> however the data previously present in my .txt file gets overwritten by the data inputted

This is false. Your code works.
Here is what I executed:

```
def tilføjMedlem():
    while True:
        tilføjFornavn = input("Skriv fornavn på det medlem du ønsker at tilføje: (Tast q for at afslutte)")
        if tilføjFornavn == 'q':
            break
        else:
            tilføjEfternavn= input("Efternavn:")
            tilføjJollypoints= input("Jollypoints:")
            tilføjInstagram = input("Instagram:")
            tilføjMedlemSiden = input('Medlem siden:')

    with open('fans.txt', 'a') as text_file:
        text_file.write(tilføjFornavn+" "+tilføjEfternavn+" "+tilføjJollypoints+" "+tilføjInstagram+" "+tilføjMedlemSiden)

tilføjMedlem()
```

Original file:

> This is the original data

Script execution:

```
Skriv fornavn på det medlem du ønsker at tilføje: (Tast q for at afslutte)
>>>? n
Efternavn:
>>>? First input
Jollypoints:
>>>? second input
Instagram:
>>>? third input
Medlem siden:
>>>? and this is the last one.
Skriv fornavn på det medlem du ønsker at tilføje: (Tast q for at afslutte)
>>>? q
```

Final file:

> This is the original data
>
> q First input second input third input and
>   this is the last one.

If the intended behavior is that **EVERY** inputs append to the file, you have to change the indent of the `with` block:

```
def tilføjMedlem():
    while True:
        tilføjFornavn = input("Skriv fornavn på det medlem du ønsker at tilføje: (Tast q for at afslutte)")
        if tilføjFornavn == 'q':
            break
        else:
            tilføjEfternavn= input("Efternavn:")
            tilføjJollypoints= input("Jollypoints:")
            tilføjInstagram = input("Instagram:")
            tilføjMedlemSiden = input('Medlem siden:')

        with open('fans.txt', 'a') as text_file:
            text_file.write(tilføjFornavn+" "+tilføjEfternavn+" "+tilføjJollypoints+" "+tilføjInstagram+" "+tilføjMedlemSiden)

tilføjMedlem()
```

Comment: Don't `q` quit after enter first 4 values. Try entering another 4 values and then `q`

Comment: I did it. And it is not a code issue, maybe a behavior issue. Since the issue pointed by the OP is the overwriting of data previously stored in the file, it is not the issue.

Comment: @TrineKlitgaardSørensen Please clear the confusion with DorianTurba and let us know if the solution posted worked for as per your requirement or not.

Comment: If the issue is, as written in the question: `data previously present in my .txt file gets overwritten by the data inputted`, then there is no solution since data isn't overwritten. If the question is: `Previous inputs gets overwritten by new inputs` then the solution is the `write` indent. Actually, the code works perfectly as I expect.